# Binding function to textblock in listbox c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I'm learning MVVM so it can be newbie questions.

**I need to bind the function:**

```
private void doubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
```

**in the textblock :**

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="mediaList" Grid.Row="1"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Medias}"
             IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Models:Media}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="icon-play-128.png" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                        <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                            <MouseBinding Command="{Binding DoubleClick}" Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" />
                        </TextBlock.InputBindings>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

but the first problem is that DoubleClick is in my view-model and not in my class media (in Model).

The other problem is that I need to receive two parameters how can I do this?

If you have better ways to do please explain to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To link Command and its Execute method, you can use delegates. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.inputbinding(v=vs.100).aspx) has very good example demonstrating this. See the example there.
2. Secondly, you are actually trying to handle MouseDoubleClick event. But MouseDoubleClick event is exposed by [Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control(v=vs.110).aspx) class. And [TextBlock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock(v=vs.100).aspx) is not a Control. So, best would be to wrap your TextBlock inside a ContentControl.

   ```
   <ContentControl MouseDoubleClick="ContentControl_MouseDoubleClick">
           <TextBlock ... />
   </ContentControl>
   ```

Then from your event handler, invoke your command programmatically.

3. If you want to keep everything de-coupled, and handling that event is very important, then write a behavior. In that Behavior, you can attach your MouseDoubleClick event handler, and do whatever you like. You can introduce your own properties in a Behavior suitable for your needs.

   ```
   using System.Windows.Interactivity;

   public class MyBehavior : Behavior<ContentControl>
   { 
        public MyBehavior()
        {}

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            AssociatedObject.MouseDoubleClick += AssociatedObject_MouseDoubleClick;
            base.OnAttached();
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            AssociatedObject.MouseDoubleClick -= AssociatedObject_MouseDoubleClick;
        }

        void AssociatedObject_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // do something
        }
   }
   ```

XAML usage :

```
<ContentControl ...
      xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" >
   <TextBlock .../>
   <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
       <local:MyBehavior />       
   </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time :)